# Height, min-height issues on iphone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, css, ipad

This is a strange problem that you can see if you understand.
It works on **desktop-browsers** – as well as **chrome/safari on iPad**.

But **not on the chrome/safari on the iphone**, which is odd.

And I am not using any media-queries at all.

This is the link:
**http://treativ.se/astadforum/**

I use standard viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

I have one solution that is not good enough. If I set a fixed pixelwidth for the viewports device-width. Than the heights are all okey, taking 100% of the height. But I would not like to hardcode the viewport-width:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=768">
```

Down below is the screenshots. The "hand" and modules below are meant to take up 100% height each. But as you can see, this fails when using device-width. The 100% height does not work - unless I hardcode the width in viewport - not desirable at all.

**WORKS :: IOS IPAD -CHROME/SAFARI**

[image: ios-ipad]

### -

**DOES NOT WORK :: IOS IPHONE -CHROME/SAFARI**

[image: ios-ipad]

Answer (score 2):

I have done lots of looking into this.

I solved this by setting the html for 200% in height for the html-tag for iPhones via media-query. Not an acceptable solution I would say - but that is how I did it.

And I had to modify the viewport for the Android phones since the emulator of the Android I had did not take the standard viewport in a good manner at all.

I do believe there is one issue of the device-width being set to 320px in width, setting it manually to 640 instead solved it.

But now I used 200% instead.. and yeah.

I have read a whole lot, but there are more problems than solutions. I do not like responsive solutions.